Elementor Popup with dynamic content from POD custom field for CPT with loop grid
I created a custom post type (Teams) with POD. And also created 7 custom fields with POD for Teams. (I am using Elememtor and Elementor Pro with Hello Elementor theme). I used Loop Grid element to show those posts dynamically. That's why I created a template for this with Call to Action element. And I designed as my client's requirements. So, all posts are showing with those custom field values dynamically with this template.
I need a popup when the end-user clicks on any post. That's why I also created a template for Popup. And trying to show the custom field value dynamically that I created with POD. Suppose, I want to show the value of member_name field. But, not showing any value if I select member_name field (Please see the 1st screenshot).  But, it is showing the value of member_name field from all posts on the Popup if I select Shortcode (Please see the 2nd screenshot). One value shows only for one post if I use shortcode with ID ([pods name="teams" id="191"]{@member_name}[/pods]) (Please see the 3rd screenshot). But, there are all values shows if I use shortcode without ID [pods name="teams"]{@member_name}[/pods] (Please see the last screenshot).
I have searched the articles and videos to resolve this problem. But, none of them help me.
I need help from the expert developer. Thanks.




